# How to Pivot with Daily Averages based on Times in Excel?

Tags: excel, macos, pivot-table

This sheet contains a call log where there are a variable amount of calls per day, with a variable amount of call durations. My goal is to create a chart that shows the number of calls as each day passes, but also show the average call duration per day.

I am getting stuck on the pivot table where I want to gather a column of Average of Call Duration. Problem is I can't figure out a way for to tell Excel to calculate the average on the amount of calls per day. The current table shows Call Duration as hh:mm:ss, and I want to show the Average of Call Duration as mm:ss, especially in the chart.

Attaching same picture of values and how my pivot table currently looks.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**To summarize, I need to figure out**

1. Tell Excel that the average is based on hh:mm:ss so it doesn't cause
   issues (if there's that chance) Tell Excel to calculate averages per
   day

Thanks!
**(Using Excel for Mac 2011)**

http://s22.postimg.org/w1op2ue0h/Pivot.png (values of the table)
http://s22.postimg.org/bt1bh4epd/Values.png (pivot from those values where you see avg duration 1442.00)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the pivot table, put the date into the row labels box and the duration into the ∑ Values box.

Click on the down arrow where it says Sum of Duration and select Value Field Settings.

Change Sum to Average under Summarize Field By.

Click the Number Format button and choose a Time format e.g. hh:mm:ss (or you can choose mm:ss from the Custom option).

The average duration for each day should be shown in hh:mm:ss or mm:ss format.

[image]

Comment: WOW Tom! Thanks so much! I wish I could upvote. This really cut down 90% of my problem!!

Comment: However, I do have a followup question. Just as you recommended, I also added another column in the Values. This happens to be a number, not time. So when I create a chart, it doesn't work (I guess since it has to check time, and number). Here's a screenshot: http://postimg.org/image/7xx5goo1n/

Comment: Glad it helped! Have you tried selecting your Pivot Table and clicking on Pivot Table Tools at the top and then Pivot Chart from the ribbon and accepting (say) the first chart type? The chart should look kind of OK, but there is a problem because the number and the time have very different scales. This is because the times are really in fractions of a day, so none of them are more than about .001 . It's OK if you chart them separately, you can change scales and axis number formats, but if you really wanted them on the same chart you'd need to convert your times into minutes t X 24 X 60.

Comment: Tom, based on what you said, I was able to tinker around more - and found that selecting the second line and changing axis to secondary just saved the day!

Comment: Must admit I hadn't thought of using a secondary axis - good solution.